# Googlescript 'if' question - do only one of two tasks

Tags: if-statement, google-apps-script

I have 'else if' statements and I need it to be called only if the previous 'if' does not execute. First 'if' (check status) work perfect, second work to, but the 'else if' is done every time because there are different types in the table (A, B, C e.t.c)

Edit:
1. New line must be add if there's no open A;
2. If there are open more than one A - all are must be closed;
3. Ignore all other types and add new line only if there are no As open;

Here is my code:

```
function myFunction() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetName');
  var data = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  var nextRow = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getLastRow()+1;

  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
    var row = data[i];
    var type = row[0];
    var status = row[1];

//check it always     
    if (status != 'close'){

//check first and if it's true don't do 'else if'      
       if (type == 'A') {
         sheet.getRange(i+2,2).setValue('close')
       }

//this should only be called if the previous 'if' is not true      
      else if (type != 'A' && type != ''){
        var values = [['A','open']];
        sheet.getRange("A"+nextRow+":B"+nextRow).setValues(values); 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: *but the 'else if' is done every time* What makes you think so?

Comment: Because in the first column I always have some items (types) that have open status (second column), so 'else if' will be called.
I added an example to the description

Comment: In example1, `type != 'A' && type != ''` will be satisfied for row2:``B:open``:i.e., status !=="close":`true`>type=="A":`false`>else if called > `type != 'A' && type != ''`:`true`, hence else if block executed.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. What needs to be changed for example one to change for type A status to close  and not add a line in the last line ('else if')?

Comment: If A1 is ``example1``, A4:B4 = `B:Open`, So,  since it's type is not A, else if  block is executed for that row. The loop checks each row from top to bottom. When it reaches A4:B4, new line is added. When it reaches A5:B5(``A:open``), B5 is changed to `close`. Do you understand?

Comment: Yes, I understand. The question is how to change the code so that it would do 'if' or 'else if', not both?

Comment: I don't think you do. For Row4, A4:B4, First ``if`` is true, second ``if`` is false and therefore ``else if`` is evaluated. To be clear, If second ``if``  is true the `else if` is **never** evaluated. But all this is done per row/for each row. Question is "*Why don't you want to add line: "A:open" in example1*"? True, Row5 is A:Open, but  before that, Row4 is B:Open, which means a line should be added.

Comment: Problem is that's I need this if statement only for type A, others - B, C, e.c.t. has own. I know that script read row by row, but maybe apply somehow break? But I didn't know how.

Comment: You can `break` in the second `if`. But, note that row5 comes after row4. So  during the execution of row4, new line is added. After that row5 is executed, `close` changes to `open` and `break`s if break is present. Problem is  your logic isn't clear. 1.When exactly do you want add a new line? 2. What if there are two or more ``A:open``s? 3. Do you ignore all other types and add new line only if there are no As open? [Edit] your question to clarify the 3 questions and logic. Currently the answer to ur Q is **First 'if' (check status) work perfect, second work too 'else if' also works perfect**

Comment: Edit:
1. New line must be add if there's no open A;
2. If there are open more than one A - all are must be closed;
3. Ignore all other types and add new line only if there are no As open

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Flow:

- Loop through all  data to find if there's a "A:Open"
- If found in all of data, just close that row
- else, Add a new line: "A:Open"
- Use a Boolean variable(`isThereASingleAOpen`) to keep track of A:Open found status

#### Sample script:

```
function closeAandAddOpenA() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SheetName');

  //Separate range and data
  var range = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow(), 2);
  var data = range.getValues();

  //Is there a A Open in the data? Let's assume there's none
  var isThereASingleAOpen = false;

  //Loop through data array
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var row = data[i];
    var type = row[0];
    var status = row[1];

    //If status is != close and type == 'A'
    if (status != 'close' && type == 'A') {
      //Change current row status to close in the data array
      row[1] = 'close';
      //Oops We were wrong. There was a A open in the data
      isThereASingleAOpen = true;
    }
  } //Loop closed

  //Set the modified data back to the range
  //Batch  operations are faster
  range.setValues(data);

  //if there is NOT a single A open in all of data, Append a new line
  if (!isThereASingleAOpen) {
    sheet.appendRow(['A', 'Open']);
  }
}
```